# mouse out event handler not working when mouse over event handler is a there in Google chart script

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pygooglechart

For below code mouse out handler not working, but when i removed mouse over relevant  code works fine. (due to chart.draw() not working properly). Guys can u give me hand to this problem.

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
        legend: 'none',
        pieSliceText: 'percentage',
        slices: { }
    };

    var chart = new   google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function(e) {

        var slices = options.slices ;
        slices[e.row] = {};
        options['slices'] = slices;            
        chart.draw(data,options);
      } 
    );  // mouse out end

   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(e) {

       var sliceid= e.row;
       console.log("mouse over"+sliceid);
       var slices = options.slices ;
       slices[e.row] = {offset:0.2};
       options['slices'] = slices;
       chart.draw(data,options);
           }
    );   // mouse over end
  }
```

Comment: Weird bug, seems it doesnt work if you add both events listener, but removing the mouseover make the mouseout work

Comment: But I need both events to my chart. I checked by removing the code in both event handlers and placed an 'alert' messages , both events worked fine, total problem with chart.draw(data, options) in event handlers only.

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem is mouseover fires repeteadly so chart redraws all the time, not giving enough time for the mouseover event to fire. This should make it work:

```
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(e) {
       var sliceid= e.row;
       var slices = options.slices ;
       if(slices.hasOwnProperty(e.row)){
           if(slices[e.row].hasOwnProperty('offset')) return false // if still mouseover, skip
       }
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qm7f86ez/